# Docker - Spring boot application with profile

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I have a docker image of a Spring boot application which is created by a developer from a different team. I'm trying to run this image on my Mac.

This application expects a profile name while starting the application. The properties file corresponding to that profile tries to locate a config file on the host machine.

Contents of application-local.properties

```
spring.config.import=file:/Users/userName/app.properties
```

Docker command I tried:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=local" application-name:0.0.1
```

This command fails with this exception as it is not able to access the file on the host machine.

```
01:09:20.764 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource 'file [/Users/userName/app.properties]' via location 'file:/Users/userName/app.properties' cannot be found
```

I tried to use the `-v` flag to bind this directory on the host to some directory on the container but it still failed.

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /Users/userName:/app -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=local" application-name:0.0.1
```

Exception-

```
02:50:36.882 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter - Application failed to start due to an exception
    org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataResourceNotFoundException: Config data resource 'file [/Users/userName/app.properties]' via location 'file:/Users/userName/app.properties' cannot be found
```

The ENTRYPOINT of this docker image is:

```
/bin/sh -c #(nop) ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh" "-c" "exec java $JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseContainerSupport -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /opt/app/app.jar"]
```

How can I run this application on my machine? Am I missing anything? TIA.

Comment: it looks like your image expects that you provide `app.properties` for the `local` profile. Could you share the command and error you got with `-v` flag.

Comment: how do you run the docker? is there any volumn mounting?

Comment: I added the command with -v flag. I'm not sure whether it's correct or not.

Comment: then try `file:/app/app.properties`

Comment: @LeiYang Do you mean like this->
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v /Users/userName:/file:/app/app.properties -e "JAVA_OPTS=-Dspring.profiles.active=local" application-name:0.0.1

Comment: no. how you run don't change. change `spring.config.import=file:/app/app.properties` of course it may break your local debugging, but make it work in docker first. then consider flexible configurations to work both.

Comment: That may work but that docker image is created some another developer. I may need to ask him to change the properties file.

Comment: you(he) can set the value as a environment variable. so it can be configured by ide or system. if you cannot change docker, try `-v /Users/userName:/Users/userName`.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the command?

Comment: i think it's nothing related to springboot, it's just docker volumn mount things. try update your docker entry point by just `cat` that file instead.

Comment: @LeiYang Using -v /Users/userName:/Users/userName worked. It was a simple trick. Thanks for your comment.